# What exactly git revert does?

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-revert

I am trying to figure out what's the difference among `git reset` , `git revert` and `git checkout`. There is something I can't understand about git revert.

I made a simple app and touch 2 file: **file1.html.erb** and **file2.html.erb**, then I subsequently created 4 commits:

commit #1: add some code in the first line of **file1.html.erb** 
commit #2: add some code in the second line of **file1.html.erb** 
commit #3: add some code in the third line of **file1.html.erb** 
commit #4: add some code in the fourth line of **file1.html.erb** and **file2.html.erb**

Basing on the case above:

---

#### git checkout

if I executing `git checkout HEAD~2`, the local file would back to the state of commit #1, nothing would be changed if I checkout to previous HEAD.

---

#### git resert --hard

`git reset HEAD~2 --hard` This would alter the commit history and local file, totally back to the state of commit #1.  While `--mixed` would change the commit history and staged snapshot, `--soft` would only change the commit history.

---

#### git revert

When I executing `git revert HEAD~2` , the terminal returned this:

`caven@CavendeMacBook-Pro ⮀ ~/demo/demo ⮀ ⭠ branch01 ⮀ git revert HEAD~2
error: could not revert ed3279f... commit 2
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
 ✘ caven@CavendeMacBook-Pro ⮀ ~/demo/demo ⮀ ⭠ branch01± ⮀`

**And in file1.html.erb , git labeled the code as:**

```
I add this line at first commit.
<<<<<<< HEAD
I add this line at second commit.
I add this line at third commit.
Simultaneously, I add this line and some code in file2 at fourth commit.
=======
>>>>>>>    parent of ed3279f... commit 2
```

**But in file2.html.erb, nothing changed, the code which I added at the fourth commit still there and git didn't label any conflict.**

This confused me, [git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) says "Given one or more existing commits, revert the changes that the related patches introduce, and record some new commits that record them."

---

I have 3 questions:

1. In this case, what exactly `git revert` is doing? Does it just compare the difference between current state and specified commit's state, then labels the conflicts?
2. I didn't specified any file, why git only labeled conflicts in file1, what about file2? How will git handle it?
3. What should I do next step? Should I delete the confilct code and create a new commit? Or should I do anything else?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Git commands tend sometimes to be overloaded with lots of different functions, and `git reset` is one such. But primarily `reset` does up-to-three-things: (1) Whatever the current branch name is (e.g., `master` or `develop`), change it to point to a new designated commit. If you choose `HEAD`, that means the same commit that it's already pointing to, so nothing actually changes. Stop here if `--soft`, else: (2) Make some changes in the index, resetting to the new `HEAD`. Stop here if `--mixed`, else (`--hard`): (3) Make some changes in the work-tree, resetting to the new HEAD.

Comment: By contrast, `git revert` is all about making a *new commit* that gets added to your current branch the way any new commit gets added to your current branch. The new commit itself is meant to reverse the effect of a previous commit of your choice.

Comment: Meanwhile, `git checkout` ... is complicated. :-) At one level it's pretty simple: it means "pick out some commit and make that the current commit". At another level it's a little scarier (it moves your `HEAD` and can "detach" it, which sounds like something guillotine-based), and at a low level it has all kinds of fun behaviors you can invoke. The main thing to think of for `git checkout <commit-or-branch>`, though, is "let me get onto and hence look at some existing commit, or the tip of a branch where I can add new ones."

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patient explaining, @torek. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revert is trying to **remove** the changes performed on revision HEAD~2, and like applying any patch, it can generate a conflict. The only revision that will be reverted with a *guaranteed* result of **no conflict** will be HEAD (if it's not a merge commit), but other revisions *might* generate a conflict (if they mess up with code that was touched on revisions after the one you want to revert. If the code involved hasn't been touched since, then it will probably be reverted cleanly ). When the revert is finished, a new revision will be created (which is different from both checkout and reset).

Comment: Thank you @Edmundo. And following what you said, I tried `git revert HEAD`. It didn't report any conflict and the code I in file2 disappear. Then I got a better understanding about what you said "Revert is trying to remove the changes performed on revision HEAD~2". It just undoes change separately, on specified commit, not linearly change all the things from the specified commit. If I only modified file1 at commit #2, it 'll only try to revert that file. But after I performed `git revert HEAD`, it returned this: (see the next comment)

Comment: Revert "same time"
    
    This reverts commit 0d7b5273d946d7296606e7260751148413398edf.

    # Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
    # with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
    # On branch branch01
    # Changes to be committed:
    #       modified:   file1.html.erb
    #       modified:   file2.html.erb
    #
    ~
    ~
    ~
    ~
    ~
"~/demo/demo/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG" 11L, 326C

Comment: It seems let me type a new commit to record this manipulation. But I don't know where to type the commit message and save it, also don't know how to quit this panel

Comment: If the editor that is popping up is "vi", the you could just write ":wq" in order to save and commit. using vi is a question of its own.

Comment: Got it. Thanks @Edmundo

Answer (score 0):

So whereas `reset --hard X` means "move my HEAD, index, and work tree to the state of `X` (along with the current branch ref if applicable), the `X` in `git revert X` is *not* a commit whose state you want to return to; it's a commit whose changes should be "undone".

In other words, `git revert HEAD~2` means "create a patch that is the opposite of what `HEAD~2` did, and make a new commit out of that to be appended at `HEAD`.

In your case, `HEAD~2` added some code to the 2nd line of file1, so the patch will remove that code.  But git notices that other code "too close for comfort" to that line has changed since `HEAD~2` happened, so it calls that a conflict.

Comment: Thank you @Mark Adelsberger. You said "not a commit whose state you want to return to; it's a commit whose changes should be 'undone'.", that really helped me understand `git revert`.